# apache2.conf vs site-avaliable virtualhost configuration

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

Manuals from google indicate that with the configurating of the apache virtual hosts it must be done through the /etc/apache2/site-aviliable(for Debian). But i configurate server via apache.conf, without site-aviliable and site-enable, and my sites work good.

What's the difference between these types of settings and how it will affect the safety / performance/something else?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all the configuration snippets will get merged into one configuration before parsing it, as if you would write them to a single file (like you actually do). So it makes no difference for the performance of apache.

However, if you put configuration values for a single vhost into a separate file, it is easy add or remove vhost by a simple file operation and therefore makes it easy to maintain and automate.